# "I" Pronunciation in a Contraction

Tags: pronouns, pronunciation

I know that pronoun "I" is pronounced as the name of the letter "I". I was listening to a song when I heard the singer said "I'm" and she pronounced it like **/ʌm/** instead of saying **/aɪm/**. And I'm sure a heard it correctly because this part of the lyrics was being repeated during the song.

---

So here is my question: Does the pronunciation of "I" **change** in a combination with "am" in a contraction? And if yes, does the same thing happen in other contractions with "I", like "I've", "I'd", etc.?

Comment: There are dialects (for example, Southern US, and some Scottish accents) where 'I' generally loses the diphthong and becomes /ʌ/ or /a/.

Comment: If the singer is using two syllables, then they are not using the contraction "I'm" but saying "I am", or not *as much* of a contraction. I think you are just hearing differences of how people speak, as there is no "correct" dialect of English. Even apart from dialect, many people have 'quirks' in their speech.

Comment: The pronunciation of 'I' doesn't _change_ in a contraction, but I think many people in casual speech would pronounce such contractions with more of an indeterminate vowel sound unless they wish to stress **I** as opposed to someone else. "**You** go on ahead and **I'll** follow in a few minutes."